# What is the correct subclass to link storyboard and swiftUI?

Tags: swift, storyboard, swiftui, subclass, nsviewcontroller

I have created the subclass below to link my swiftui code to my storyboard. The goal is to have a vstack with text containers in it display inside a ContainerView. I am not sure if I am using the right class:  NSViewController? I do not get any errors, but the code does not display how I want it to. Mostly, The swiftui does not display inside the window that shows up when I run the app.

```
import SwiftUI

class termu: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }
    @IBSegueAction func waka(_ coder: NSCoder) -> NSViewController? {
        return NSHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: ContentView())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest `MyViewController` which you can specify for new controller scene in IB for your storyboard as custom class in Identity Inspector. (The controller scene and segue creation in IB as usual).

[image: view controller]

I selected Sheet segue for demo

[image: SwiftUI segue controller]

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class MyViewController: NSHostingController<ContentView> {

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: ContentView())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View { // This SwiftUI view is just for Demo
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I'm SwiftUI")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
    }
}
```